# History push undefined when using props within Axios getData in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, prop

I'm trying to make this posts component reusable by adding in props from the parent. My props are 'pathname' and 'filter'. I have a pathname to my database I want to update and the filter which allows me to filter out the data from that database. It prints out a list of posts based on pathname and filter. This works fine, my Posts component is showing correctly.

However, when I add a click function to my singular post so that it will go to a 'FullPost' component based on post.id, I get an error saying that it 'Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'. When I don't use props but hardcode the values instead it works fine and the click works as expected, it goes to the FullPost component and url based on id.

I have tried printing out 'this.props.history' and it does show 'undefined'. I'm not sure how to make this defined and why the addition of props makes this undefined.

The parent calls it like this:

```
<Route path="/food" exact render={() => <Posts pathname="/posts" filter="food" />} />
```

It seems the render() method doesn't include the lifehooks so it doesn't include the history? However, I'm not sure how to include my props if I don't use render() instead of component={} in the Route.

Below is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from '../../../axiosPosts';

import Aux from '../../../hoc/Aux/Aux';
import classes from './Posts.css';
import Post from '../../../components/Post/Post';


class Posts extends Component {

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        //console.log('posts props: ', this.props.pathname, ', posts filter: ', this.props.filter, ', this props: ', this.props);
        this.getData(this.props.pathname, this.props.filter);
    }

    getData(pathname, filter) {

        axios.get(pathname + '.json')
        .then(response => {
            const post = response.data.filter(({category}) => category === filter);

            const updatedPosts = post.map(post => {
                return {
                    ...post
                }
            });

            this.setState({
                posts: updatedPosts
            });

            console.log( 'history: ', this.props.history );
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    postSelectedHandler = ( id ) => {
        this.props.history.push( this.props.match.url + '/' + id );
    }

    render () {
        let posts = <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Whoops! Something went wrong.</p>;

        if(!this.state.error) {
            posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
                return (
                     <Post 
                         key={post.id}
                         title={post.title}
                         dek={post.dek}
                         clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler( post.id )}     />
                );
            });
        };
        return (
            <Aux>
                 <div className={classes.PostList}>
                     <h2 className={classes.PostListTitle}>{this.props.filter}</h2>
                    {posts}
                </div>
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props):

```
<Route path="/food" exact render={(routeProps) => <Posts pathname="/posts" filter="food" {...routeProps} />} />
```

or (if you need just `history`):

```
<Route path="/food" exact render={({history}) => <Posts pathname="/posts" filter="food" history={history} />} />
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, I just found the initial answer too but didn't know you can target just history, that is very handy.

Comment: Yeah, I also don't see if you bound component context to getData() - if you don't, this will fail b/c it needs for correct this.setState() call

Comment: You mean add this?    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);

Comment: Yep, in `constructor`